# mysql: add subquery to existing query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to sql, during my internship i was required to know a bit of sql so i started learning and was allowed to practice on the test environment(no updating, inserting or deleting but just displaying ), while practicing i had this question,this is my existing query:

```
Select 
ab.USER_ID,
user.email AS email, 
concat(user.firstName, ' ' ,user.lastName ) AS name, 
usl.loginDateTime AS LastLogin,
ab.creation_time AS DateJoined,
udl.devicePlatform AS Devices,
user.status AS Status
FROM F_USR_USER AS user

INNER JOIN F_USR_ACCOUNT_BASE AS ab 
on user.ID= ab.USER_ID

INNER JOIN F_USR_DSL_LOG AS udl
ON ab.USER_ID=udl.USER_ID

INNER JOIN F_USR_SESSION_LOG AS usl
ON ab.USER_ID=usl.USER_ID
group by ab.USER_ID
```

I want to insert this select into this query.I tried with union all and a select within an inner join but it didn't work(maybe the structure was wrong)

This is the query i need to add.This query displays the number of downloaded documents for each user with User_id as the foreign key for all tables that i used in this query.

```
Select ab.user_id,count(*) as total
 from F_USR_ACCOUNT_BASE AS ab ,F_USR_DOCUMENT AS doc
 where ab.USER_ID= doc.USER_ID and doc.extractionComplete = '1'
 group by ab.user_ID;
```

What do i use to get it correctly?

Comment: A quick scan of your first query the `FROM` is missing before you start the JOINS.

Comment: @JohnMcMahon That looks like a simple copying error, it's presumably before `F_USR_USR AS user`.

Comment: Why does your original query have a `GROUP BY` clause? It doesn't have any aggregation functions like `MAX` or `COUNT`.

Comment: I used group by to avoid duplicates

Comment: So shouldn't you use `MAX(usl.loginDateTime) AS LastLogin`? Otherwise it will pick some random row from `F_USR_SESSION_LOG`, which probably won't be the last login. And `Devices` will just be a randomly chosen device, maybe you want `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT udl.devicePlatform) AS Devices`.

Comment: fyi i changed the title because `insert select` means something specific, and it isn't this.

Comment: Devices come from another table that stores the list. For now each user has only one device and login time attached to it. I used group by because i would be getting a new entry for each device, login times etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  One way is to add it to the select clause:

```
Select 
ab.USER_ID,
user.email AS email, 
concat(user.firstName, ' ' ,user.lastName ) AS name, 
usl.loginDateTime AS LastLogin,
ab.creation_time AS DateJoined,
udl.devicePlatform AS Devices,
user.status AS Status,
(
    Select  count(*) as total
    from    F_USR_DOCUMENT AS doc
    where   ab.USER_ID= doc.USER_ID 
    and     doc.extractionComplete = '1'
) as totalDocs
From
F_USR_USER AS user
INNER JOIN 
F_USR_ACCOUNT_BASE AS ab on 
    user.ID= ab.USER_ID
INNER JOIN 
F_USR_DSL_LOG AS udl ON 
    ab.USER_ID=udl.USER_ID
INNER JOIN 
F_USR_SESSION_LOG AS usl ON 
    ab.USER_ID=usl.USER_ID
group by ab.USER_ID /* Maybe take this GROUP BY out.  WHERE clause to filter. */
```

Comment: I don't have privileges to add comments, but I just wanted to comment about how you say you're using a group by clause to avoid duplicates.  I'd recommend avoiding that if you can.  In many causes, you can remove duplicates by editing the WHERE clause.  From my experience, it makes it easier to read, and it makes your intention easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can join with a subquery.

```
Select 
    ab.USER_ID,
    user.email AS email, 
    concat(user.firstName, ' ' ,user.lastName ) AS name, 
    usl.loginDateTime AS LastLogin,
    ab.creation_time AS DateJoined,
    udl.devicePlatform AS Devices,
    user.status AS Status,
    doc.total AS TotalDocs
FROM F_USR_USER AS user

INNER JOIN F_USR_ACCOUNT_BASE AS ab 
    on user.ID= ab.USER_ID

INNER JOIN F_USR_DSL_LOG AS udl
    ON ab.USER_ID=udl.USER_ID

INNER JOIN F_USR_SESSION_LOG AS usl
ON ab.USER_ID=usl.USER_ID

INNER JOIN (
    Select user_id, count(*) as total
    from F_USR_DOCUMENT
    where extractionComplete = '1'
    group by user_ID) AS doc
) ON doc.user_id = ab.user_id

group by ab.USER_ID
```

Comment: I tried this method but it didn't work for me. I was getting an error code.1248  ER_DERIVED_MUST_HAVE_ALIAS, "Every derived table must have its own alias".

Comment: I have an alias: `AS doc`. I don't have any other derived tables in my query.